# JUnit report showing empty values

Tags: ant, junit

I am using JUnitReport with Ant to generate my test cases report. 
The build file runs successfully but it is showing empty values. Like in the Style sheet , I am seeing the framed output having

- Test 0
- Failures 0
- Success Rate NaN
- Time 0.00

Here is my build.xml file

```
<project name="JunitTest" default="test" basedir="."> 
<property name="testdir" location="./bin" /> 
<property name="srcdir" location="." /> 
<property name="full-compile" value="true" /> 
<property name="test.reports" value="./reports" />

<path id="classpath.base"/>
<path id="classpath.test">

<path id="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath">
      <pathelement location="./lib/junit-4.1.jar"/>
      <pathelement location=".lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
</path>

<pathelement location="${testdir}" />
<pathelement location="${srcdir}" />

<path refid="classpath.base" />

</path> 

<target name="clean" >
    <echo> CLEAN </echo>
    <delete verbose="${full-compile}"> 
        <fileset dir="${testdir}" includes="**/*.class" />
    </delete> 
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean">
    <echo> COMPILING </echo>
    <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${testdir}" verbose="${full-compile}" >
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
        <classpath refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="compile" >

    <junit printsummary="true" showoutput="true">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
        <classpath refid="JUnit 4.libraryclasspath" />
        <formatter type="plain"  />
        <formatter type="plain"  />

        <test name="com.megacorp.projx.JUnit.AllTests" />
    </junit>

    <junitreport todir="${test.reports}" >
        <fileset dir="${test.reports}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report todir="${test.reports}"  format="frames" />
    </junitreport>
    <record name="${test.reports}/test-output.txt" action="start"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Your junit does not use test.reports property. Where do the TEST-*xml go?

Comment: I am using test.report property. I have created the folder naming reports under my project directory where junit creates all the html files, but having all the values 0. Also file created under the folder reports TESTS-TestSuites.xml is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set todir attribute in your `test`  block

```
<test name="com.megacorp.projx.JUnit.AllTests"  todir="${test.reports}" />
```

If you are just learning junit ant task, please check the `batchtest` task. It can pickup tests based on filters.